# Laravel increment column in updateOrCreate and get the model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to increment a column and updateorcreate a record in one query by doing so:

```
$model = Model::updateOrCreate([
   'email' => $email
], ['received_at' => $received_at])->incremet('received_count');
```

This does the job as I wanted it too. It updates or create a record and increments the `received_count` column.

But after the query, I wanted to get the updated/created row, but when I log `$model`, it only logs `0 or 1`. I can confirm that this is because of the `->increment()`.

But to be honest, I don't know any way how to increment the `received_count` column other than how I currently did it.

How do I achieve so that it updates or create a record, at the same time increments the `received_count` column, and after all of this, returns the updated/created object?

**As much as posssible, I want this all in one query. Getting the model should be a memory**.

Comment: Check the 2nd example of Laravel's `tap` method here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-tap, you should be able to do the same in your code: `$model = tap(Model::updateOrCreate(...))->increment('received_count');`. Doing that, `$model` should be the Model instance, and not `0` or `1`. I can't test this right now, but let me know if that works and I'll convert to an answer.

Comment: Hi @TimLewis, I ended up using your answer, it works. So does the answers below. Correct me if I'm wrong... I ended up using this answer since I think this gets the model in memory, and not re-querying from the table unlike `refresh() and fresh()`.

If I'm wrong, can you enlighten me as to why this is better than `refresh() or fresh()`?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure how the `tap()` method works behind the scenes... You might still need to call `fresh()` or `refresh()`, if the `received_count` is off-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$model = Model::updateOrCreate(['email' => $email], ['received_at' => $received_at]);

$model->increment('received_count');
$model->refresh(); // this will refresh all information for your model.
```

or you can simply:

```
$model = Model::updateOrCreate(['email' => $email], ['received_at' => $received_at]);
tap($model)->increment('id'); // this will return refreshed model.
```

Comment: I think this answer is one solution so I'm going to upvote this. But I'm not able to upvote this. I don't have enoug reputation.

Comment: You can click left side of this answer "checkmark" so it will mark this answer as an "answer" no need to upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

just fresh model after incremet:

```
  $model = Model::updateOrCreate([
            'email' => $email
        ], ['received_at' => $received_at]);
        $model->incremet('received_count');
        $model->fresh();
```

Comment: I can see that this works as well as `refresh()` stated by @gguney. But I'm curious, is `fresh() and refresh()` memory state? Or is it another query?

Comment: refresh() will refresh current model (including relationships),fresh() will get new instance of model from the database and return it. @jthinam